# How to create a simple jQuery image slider without absolute position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

I'm looking for a way to create a very simple image slider using jQuery with animated fade transition. No buttons, numbers nor legends are necessary.

I've found this [very good example here](http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/simplest-jquery-slideshow) -- and a few others -- but the problem is that they all require the images to be on "position:absolute" and when I do it my whole layout is crashed.

Is there any way I can do it without having to use absolute positioning on images?

This is the original code I'm using:

```js
$(function(){
    $('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();
    setInterval(function(){
      $('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut()
         .next('img').fadeIn()
         .end().appendTo('.fadein');}, 
      3000);
});
```

```css
.fadein { position:relative; width:500px; height:332px; }
.fadein img { position:absolute; left:0; top:0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fadein">
  <img src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2610/4148988872_990b6da667.jpg">
  <img src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2597/4121218611_040cd7b3f2.jpg">
  <img src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2531/4121218751_ac8bf49d5d.jpg">
</div>
```

I'm not really sure why my layout crashes when I use position:absolute on images. See the image below, since the image is position:absolute the text that should be positioned below the image is position over the image:

[image]

The way I found to solve this is to set the div height dynamically according to the image height, but I know this is not elegant. Still accepting any ideas or comments. Thanks!

```js
function adjustScreenSize() {
  var img = document.getElementById('imgslide');
  var height = img.clientHeight;
  document.getElementById('slideshow').style.height = height + "px";
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  adjustScreenSize();
});

$(window).resize(function() {
  adjustScreenSize();
});
```

```css
#slideshow { 
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
}

#slideshow img {
 left: 50%;
 top: 0;
 width: 80%;
 margin-left: -40%;
 height: auto;
 position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="row text-center">

  <div class="col-md-12">

    <div class="top-buffer-lg bottom-buffer-md blue">
      <h1>All you need to know in one single place</h1>
      <span>A well designed product to help you keep track of SaaS and subscription metrics</span>
    </div>

    <!-- ** SCREEN SHOTS ** -->
    <div id="slideshow">
      <img id="imgslide" src="img/saasmetrics-screen-01.png" />
      <img src="img/saasmetrics-screen-02.png" />
      <img src="img/saasmetrics-screen-03.png" />
      <img src="img/saasmetrics-screen-04.png" />
    </div>

  </div>

</div><!--/row-->
```

Comment: the problem to solve IMHO is 'why is your layout crashed' by that?

Comment: @bondythegreat please check it out, i've just included my original code at the post.

Answer (score 3):

You can use css think about vendor prefix or use prefixfree

```css
.fadein { 
  position:relative; 
  width:500px; 
  height:332px; 
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-animation: slider 6s infinite alternate
}
@-webkit-keyframes slider {
  from{
    background: url(http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2610/4148988872_990b6da667.jpg)
  }
  50%{
    background: url(http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2597/4121218611_040cd7b3f2.jpg)
  }
  to{
    background: url(http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2531/4121218751_ac8bf49d5d.jpg)
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="fadein"></div>
```

Comment: How could I make it work with for images instead of three? Thanks.

Comment: @LeandroFaria just set the %tage  something like `from{} 25%{}50%{}75%{}to{}` then you will need to ajust the `animation: slider 6s infinite alternate` where 6 is the value you will change

Comment: That almost works. The only problem here is that my image can't have a fixed width/height. I need image to be width:80% and height:auto -- so the layout remains responsive.

Answer (score 1):

```
 var i= -1;
       var images = [];
       images[0] = "fingers.jpg";
       images[1] = "tmrw.jpg";
       images[2] = "cycle.jpg";

    function changeImg(){
         time = 3000;            
        if(i < images.length - 1)
        {
          i++; 
        }
        else 
        { 
         i = 0;
        }
         setTimeout("changeImg()", time);
         document.slide.src = images[i];

    }     
    window.onload=changeImg;

       function prev()
        {
           i = i-1;
          if ( i < images.length )
          {
            if ( i == -1 )
            {
                i = 2;
            }
          }
          document.slide.src = images[i];
        }

        function next()
        {
          i = i +1;

         if ( i <= images.length  )
         {
            if ( i == images.length )
            {
                i = 0;
            }
         }
            document.slide.src = images[i];
        }
```